# In API design, when should I prefer a length-2 std::tuple over a pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair, idioms, stdtuple

I'm writing a small library which has some API function returning two things (of different types). I'd rather not declare a struct just for that; so I'm thinking of returning an `std::pair<foo, bat>`. But - perhaps in these modern times I should prefer returning `std::tuple<foo, bar>` instead?

More generally, when should a tuple be prefered over a pair, and when is pair the more appropriate construct?

Comment: In these modern times, a struct with appropriately-named members is far superior to a `std::pair` with members named `first` and `second`, as well as to a `std::tuple` with members named `get<0>()` and `get<1>()`.

Comment: if the two values are related, ex employee id, employee name then struct would be better in my opinion.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the use case in your API design?

Comment: Make a proper struct with proper names; it's four lines of definition for you, but an order of magnitude of readability for your library clients. I'm sick of lazy APIs where it's all `stuff.first.second`, `stuff.second.first`, they are long to type and it's never clear what is going on. Just look at any code that works with `std::map` iterators (doubly so if the key or the value is itself a pair) - there's really no excuse for that kind of lazy design.

Comment: Related: https://www.kdab.com/tuple-pair-cpp-apis/

Comment: See also the C++ core guidelines [F.21](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out-multi) and [E.27](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Re-no-throw-codes).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How about, say, `std::pair<wheel_id_t, wheel_id_t> get_front_wheels(const car_t& car)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should declare a struct for that.

`get<0>(x)` and `get<1>(x)`, or even post-C++11's `get<Foo>(x)` and `get<Bar>(x)`, are less meaningful and/or idiomatic than `x.foo` or `x.bar`.

`tuple`s are best for non-uniformly typed things that are identified by order.

`pair`s are a `tuple` that was written prior to C++11.

Both `pair` and `tuple` (and `array` while we are at it) are tuple-like, in that they support `std::tuple_size` and `get<N>`.

It has been considered an error in the `std` library that so many types use `pair` instead of structures with properly named fields.  Ie, if `map` used `struct KV{ Key key; Value value; }`, it would have been better.

Now, metaprogramming support for `KV` as a generic pair would be good as well.  So, `tuple_size` and `get<0>` etc.  But throwing away named fields is generally a bad idea.  Names have power.

With C++17, simple `struct`s start working with structured binding, even if you don't make them "tuple-like".

If you do have things whose identity is determined by their order of non-uniform type, `tuple` is the way to go.  `pair` is a nearly legacy type.  There are some advantages to `pair` over `tuple`, but `tuple` continues to be improved to remove them (like implicit initialization of `tuple`).

Answer (score 0):

> But - perhaps in these modern times I should prefer returning `std::tuple<foo, bar>` instead?
>
> More generally, **when should a tuple be prefered over a pair**, and when is pair the more appropriate construct?

Well, it might be useful in case you want to work with (meta-)algorithms that rather expect to take a `std::tuple` than a `std::pair`.

Finally that is absolutely dependent on your actual use case and cannot be answered without knowing it.

If you have a situation that is guaranteed to match a pair of types intrinsically (semantically related in the context) you might be better off with `std::pair` to reflect those semantics at the API.

If you're not sure, rather use a `std::tuple` to keep on for future flexibility of your API design.

Another way is simply to use your own structs that clearly have named semantics for the values like:

```
 template<typename T>
 struct point2D {
      T x;
      T y;
 };

 template<typename T>
 struct point3D {
      T x;
      T y;
      T z;
 };

 template<typename Key, typename Value>
 struct Item {
     Key key:
     Value value;
 };
```

rather than `std::tuple<T,T>`, `std::pair<T,T>` or `std::tuple<T,T,T>`

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are meant for wrapping around multiple values that may or may not have any relations to each other.

Pairs are meant for wrapping around two pairs of values that has a relation between each other ex. a key-value pair would have two values, one being a key and the other being a value, where they both have a relation to each other ex. in a hashmap where the key points to either the pair or the value.

It really comes down in how you want everything to work etc.

Comment: No, that's not what pairs are meant for. That's just how they were inappropriately used by the standard library. If you have a key-value pair, the appropriate structure for that is a struct with a member named key and a member named value.

Answer (score 0):

I've commonly seen proper API calls or libraries (math related) return a struct or class even if the container has two values.

But if you must, I agree with @Bauss, if the value is a key, value pair then use `std::pair`, for example "table id, string name".

But if the tuple is not key value but both are actual values for example a position is XY coordinate  (int x, int y) use `std::tuple`.

Comment: Well, that doesn't apply for using `std::pair` like 2D coordinate points, which are also a popular use.

Comment: The frameworks or lib's I've used so far never used either `std::pair` nor `std::tuple` for containing coordinate points. For example OpenFramework uses ofVec2f, Qt uses QPoint, UDK uses FVector2D, etc...

Comment: @ArmenB: ... especially because pairs and tuples miss the usual operator overloading stuff, which makes them a lot more awkward to use as coordinate points.

Comment: @Matteo true, so maybe coordinate point isn't the best example for his case.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: some of what follows is opinion:

In computer science, there are only three interesting numbers:

- zero
- one
- N

Because we're either dealing with the absence of something, one thing or some number of things. For example `average(a0 , a1)` is a special case of `average(a0, ...aI)` where I is every integer in the set (0 <= I < N).

It follows that `std::pair` is logically specialisation of an N-tuple and is therefore un-needed.

Worse, using a `pair` assumes that the number of items will always be 2, and bakes that into the interface. This is obviously an error, since we're trading the ability to make future nonbreaking changes for zero gain.

When the STL was first written there were no variadic templates and there were only three use-cases for pairs :-

1. as a range resulting from `equal_range` and the like
2. as an iterator-with-state returned from `map::insert` and,
3. as a key/value pair in a `map`.

Then boost came along with its modern ideas like tuples. Being an unofficial library, boost was able to simulate variadic templates with pages and pages of auto-generated overloads. Something that would be unthinkable in a standardised API that ships with every compiler.

Now we have variadic templates. Except where unfortunately baked into the interfaces of maps, there is no reason whatsoever to prefer a `pair` over a `tuple`

Comment: Even when the STL was written, the decision of returning `std::pair` was a very poor decision; a named struct would've been much better. `auto i = map.insert(key, value); if (i.first) { /* or i.second? can never remember... */ }`.

Comment: "*Worse, using a pair assumes that the number of items will always be 2, and bakes that into the interface.*" Because functions don't have baked in numbers of parameters. Oh wait... "*there is no reason whatsoever to prefer a pair over a tuple*" Unless you need a type which is trivially copyable and/or standard layout. `tuple` is neither.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's true that I had not considered this standard-layout use case. However it seems to me that in such a case, it would be more expressive and trivial to simply create a new struct that did this job in 3 lines of code (excluding braces). If we truly need standard layout 2-tuples, we can simply use std::tie around a trivial struct and achieve the same effect. I did offer the warning about the presence of opinion.

Comment: So, is the standard committee entertaining the possibility of deprecating `std::pair` at some point? e.g. for a "version 2" of the standard library?

Comment: **Worse, using a pair assumes that the number of items will always be 2, and bakes that into the interface. This is obviously an error.* I completely disagree. That's like saying that having a non-variadic signature with 2 (separate) parameters bakes in the number of parameters at 2. We don't write infinitely fluid code that can take whatever you throw at it.

Comment: @einpoklum: bad example, you can add parameters without breaking the API by adding an overload (which won't even break the ABI) or adding parameters with a default value (actually, it's routinely done); you can add stuff to a returned struct without impacting your client code (again, routinely done); however you will break it if you change the return type from a pair to a tuple or from a tuple to a bigger one.

Comment: @einpoklum it seems futile to argue what is essentially an opinion. You will have seen that I laid out my position that a pair is logically a 2-tuple that just happens to have hard-baked names for elements 0 and 1. A tuple has a variadic signature. So it follows (to me) that a pair is a crippled tuple.

Comment: @RichardHodges: That part of the argument is fine :-)